# any idea what I do wrong with the python import error from kivy?

Tags: python, import, kivy, widget

I recently started working with kivy, and wanted to play with widgets today, but I have this error message:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import widget
```

```
line 2:    from kivy.uix.widget import widget

ImportError: cannot import name 'widget' from 'kivy.uix.widget' (C:\Users\drawcoco\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py)
```

the file is not missing, and I can open it using notepad or any python IDE

any idea what I do wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're just missing a capital. The import should be:

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
```

Comment: No problem, we all make mistakes like that sometimes. In general though, if it's a class in Python it should start with a capital so just keep an eye out

Comment: now that you say it... yes it s true, but idk I was thinking the file had 'widget' so the lib was 'widget' too xD thanks again